# $(this) only working for one item [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

I am using `$(this)` to get the css attribute of an HTML element, but it is only working for one of them. The items are the same, except all but the one that is working are being positioned relatively.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div class="red" id="color"></div>
  <div class="orange" id="color"></div>
  <div class="yellow" id="color"></div>
  <div class="green" id="color"></div>
  <div class="blue" id="color"></div>
  <div class="purple" id="color"></div>
  <div class="pink" id="color"></div>
  <div class="black" id="color"></div>
  <div class="white" id="color"></div>

  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

  <div class="space"></div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#color').click(function(){

    var color = $(this).css('background');

    $('.space').css('background',''+color+'');

  });

});
```

And this is my CSS:

```
body {
  margin-top:55px;
  margin-left:60px;
  margin-right:60px;
  margin-bottom:60px;
}

#color {
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #A3A3A3;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.red {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#8A0B0B;
}

.orange {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#E89229;
  position:relative;
  left:17px;
}

.yellow {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#EBD508;
  position:relative;
  left:34px;
}

.green {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#3B8242;
  position:relative;
  left:51px;
}

.blue {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#6E97D5;
  position:relative;
  left:68px;
}

.purple {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#542462;
  position:relative;
  left:85px;
}

.pink {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#FACCFA;
  position:relative;
  left:102px;
}

.black {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#000000;
  position:relative;
  left:119px;
}

.white {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#ffffff;
  position:relative;
  left:136px;
}

.space {
  height:657px;
  width:500px;
  border:2px solid #A3A3A3;
}
```

Do you have any ideas on how to make the jQuery work for all the divs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, the attribute `id` should be unique.

Comment: Remove the id attribute and instead add one more class named `color` and use `.color` in your JS..try that..

Comment: @Lal That doesn't seem to be working... it just messes up my positioning, and makes none of them work.

Comment: change `#color` in your CSS to `.color`..will that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have multiple of the same id's of `color`

```
<div class="red" id="color"></div>
<div class="orange" id="color"></div>
<div class="yellow" id="color"></div>
```

you can change to the following and assign classes instead to attach an event handler to all elements with a class of `.color`

```
<div class="color red"></div>
<div class="color orange"></div>
<div class="color yellow"></div>
```

---

```
$('.color').click(function() { // class selector

    var color = $(this).css('background');

    $('.space').css('background',''+color+'');
});
```

Also as mentioned in your comments regarding element styling. Since we're swapping the id for a class, remember to apply your style rules accordingly

```
#color { ... }
```

=>

```
.color { ... }
```

Comment: Two class attributes wont work...you have to do lik `<div class="red color">`

Answer (score 1):

Change the attribute `#id` to `.class`. IDS should be UNIQUE! As a rseult, your code would look like this:

```
$('.color').click(function(){    
    var color = $(this).css('background');    
    $('.space').css('background',''+color+'');    
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

ID's should be unique, change the `color` id's to classes

HTML

```
<div class="color red"></div>
<div class="color orange"></div>
<div class="color yellow"></div>
<div class="color green"></div>
<div class="color blue"></div>
<div class="color purple"></div>
<div class="color pink"></div>
<div class="color black"></div>
<div class="color white"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".color").on("click", function () {
    var color = $(this).css('background');
    $('.space').css('background-color',color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, IDs shouldn't exists more than once per page.

It should be:

```
<div id="red" class="color"></div>
<div id="orange" class="color"></div>
```

and JS as mentioned below:

```
$('.color').click(function() { // class selector    
    var color = $(this).css('background');    
    $('.space').css('background',''+color+'');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** do not use this. IDs must be unique!

Usually, jQuery uses [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to select all the elements that match a selector. `querySelectorAll` would match all the elements.

However, in your case jQuery attempts to speed things up, using the faster [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) instead of `querySelectorAll`. Therefore, only the first element is matched.

A way to avoid this behavior is using a more complex selector, like `html #color`. Currently,  `#color` (note the space) also works, but a future version of jQuery might trim the string.

```js
$('html #color').click(function(){    
    var color = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    $('.space').css('background',''+color+'');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top:55px;
  margin-left:60px;
  margin-right:60px;
  margin-bottom:60px;
}
#color {
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #A3A3A3;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.red {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#8A0B0B;
}
.orange {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#E89229;
  position:relative;
  left:17px;
}
.yellow {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#EBD508;
  position:relative;
  left:34px;
}
.green {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#3B8242;
  position:relative;
  left:51px;
}
.blue {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#6E97D5;
  position:relative;
  left:68px;
}
.purple {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#542462;
  position:relative;
  left:85px;
}
.pink {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#FACCFA;
  position:relative;
  left:102px;
}
.black {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#000000;
  position:relative;
  left:119px;
}
.white {
  height:49px;
  width:49px;
  background:#ffffff;
  position:relative;
  left:136px;
}
.space {
  height:657px;
  width:500px;
  border:2px solid #A3A3A3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red" id="color"></div>
<div class="orange" id="color"></div>
<div class="yellow" id="color"></div>
<div class="green" id="color"></div>
<div class="blue" id="color"></div>
<div class="purple" id="color"></div>
<div class="pink" id="color"></div>
<div class="black" id="color"></div>
<div class="white" id="color"></div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="space"></div>
```

Also note `background` is a shorthand property. Attempting to get the computed value of a shorthand property may produce the empty string on some browsers (e.g. Firefox). Better use `backgroundColor`.